# How to add meta data to Visual Studio C/C++ project

Tags: c, visual-studio, metadata

I made a simple program in Visual Studio and would like to distribute it. However, before I can do that, I would like to add metadata to the executable file (such as author, version, etc.) Is there any way to do this in a C or C++ project in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: yes.  Just put the data as constant strings (i.e. const char* author = "Cpp plus 1";)  This has the benefit that you can use these strings as part of the output of a version option (if command line based) or on the Help | About dialog.

Comment: What @thurizas said, but you may want to also declare them `volatile` to prevent them being removed if they are not explicitly referenced in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the VS2008 Resource view, right-click on your project.

From the pop-up menu, select Add resource.

In the dialog, select Version

A Versioning resource is added to your project (program). Double-click on it and it will be shown in the editing pane. You can adapt the standard versioning elements.

If you right-click in the editor, you can add your own blocks.

If you compile your application, the version information will be added to the executable. Right-click the excutable, select Properties and then select the Detail tab to see your information.

**Note**: when testing, the executable was now flagged harmfull by F-Secure. I reported this false positive to F-Secure.